# A misconception about cauchy's criterion for existence of limit of a function

Tags: analysis

Let us consider a function  F(x). Let's say that the limit of a function exists at a point $P$ and $Q$, but let's say the limit of that function 
doesn't exist at a point  $Q$, $Q>P$ and $Q-P= D$.

If I understand Cauchy's criterion for existence of limit for a function at a point  $A$ then, it says that if for any positive value $s$, we can find another positive value $w$, depending upon, such that  $\mod {F(x) -F(y)} < s$, whenever $x,y$ belong to $(A, w)$.

Now as mentioned earlier let us suppose that limit exists at $P$ then the above condition is satisfied at point $P$. As such for every value of $X$
and $Y$, such that $\mod[ X- Y] < s$ , for some $s >0$, whenever $X$ and $Y$ belong to the neighborhood $N (P, w)$  for some $w >0$.

Now for point $Q$ even we can have this same $X$ and $Y$ belonging to the neighborhood  $N ( Q, D+w)$,thereby satisfying Cauchy's criterion.
(Although in this case we can assure only one sided limit).

But even the one sided limit does not exists at point $Q$ shouldn't solely on the basis of whether it exists at a point which falls at a position left to this point.

So, I must be having a some misconception about it and I would like to clear it. Hoping for a reply.

Comment: The first paragraph says first that the limit exists at $Q$ and then that it doesn't. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion is the wrong way around. $(Q,D+w)\supset(P,w)$, but that doesn't help you, because to fulfill the condition in the definition you need to have arbitrarily close function values in an entire neighbourhood of $Q$, but all you know from your argument is that they're close to each other in some (small) subset of $(Q,D+w)$.

Comment: I understand but cauchy's criteria doesn't directly say about small neighborhoods far off or whether they should be near . How can we restate cauchy's criteria so that this is resolved ?

Comment: @OzymandiasAmygdala: No need to restate the Cauchy criterium; I believe you stated it correctly in the question. It's not fulfilled by the $(Q,D+w)$ you propose, since it requires "whenever $x,y$ belong to $(A,w)$". I didn't use the words "far off" or "near", so there's nothing to resolve about them.

Comment: That's where I was getting stuck, I missed the entirety of neighborhood part... Thanks